# Find and replace text inside text boxes in MS Word

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I have this procedure to realise a find and replace on a word document. Since I have text boxes, using this way to do this is a bit a slower than what I'd like it to be, if it were just text on a plain doc document or tables and using  just:

```
Document.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:=Find, MatchWholeWord:=True, ReplaceWith:=Replace, Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
```

It goes really fast. Any ideas please?

```
Sub ReplaceWord(Find As String, Replace As String, Document As Word.Document)
    Dim myStoryRange = Document.Range()
'Iterates thru all the storyranges and finds and replace with the parameters of the sub Find, Replace in Document
    For Each myStoryRange In Document.StoryRanges
        If myStoryRange.StoryType <> Word.WdStoryType.wdMainTextStory Then
            With myStoryRange.Find
                .Text = Find
                .Replacement.Text = Replace
                .Wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue
                .Execute(Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
            End With
            Do While Not (myStoryRange.NextStoryRange Is Nothing)
                myStoryRange = myStoryRange.NextStoryRange
                With myStoryRange.Find
                    .Text = Find
                    .Replacement.Text = Replace
                    .Wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue
                    .Execute(Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
                End With
            Loop
        End If
    Next myStoryRange
End Sub
```